# Pool Non paged bytes and Stack buffer overrun

Tags: windows, crash, stack-overflow, crash-dumps

Analyzing a Windows Crashdump. The cause of the crash is stack buffer overrun

```
ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000409 - The system detected an overrun of a stack-based buffer in this application. This overrun could potentially allow a malicious user to gain control of this application.

EXCEPTION_CODE_STR:  c0000409

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1:  00000005
```

Trying to understand the memory usage at the time of crash using Performance monitor.
From Performance monitor, I could see "Pool Non paged bytes" going high for the process which is crashing at the time of crash.

Is there any correlation between the "Pool Non paged bytes" and stack over run?

[image]

Comment: Code 5 is `FAST_FAIL_INVALID_ARG`.

Comment: @RaymondChen any idea when this can happen?

Comment: Look at the stack trace to see where the invalid argument came from.